# Does Mathematica implement its own methods of tracking precision?

Tags: implementation-details, arbitrary-precision

I know that for arbitrary precision arithmetic Mathematica [uses GMP](http://www.wolfram.com/LGPL/GMP/). But apart from just providing arbitrary precision, Mathematica also does precision tracking for its arbitrary-precision numbers, so that e.g.

```
1.2345`5 - 1.2300`5 // Precision
```

gives us `2.2614836912846`. Among GNU packages of the GMP family there is MPFI. But I haven't found any references that Mathematica does use it: there's no such library in installation directory (unlike `libgmp.so.10`), and it doesn't seem mentioned anywhere.

So does Mathematica actually implement precision tracking on its own, without using any well-known package for this?

Comment: Yes, mathematica implements it's own precision tracking.

Comment: @user21 your link gives "Item not found".

Comment: Not the talk I had in mind, but I can not find the other one. Maybe contact the author, [this one](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/326/) is very dated.